# How to put jasper report cross tab and time series chart in one chart

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to make jasper report which includes  time series and cross tab in one report.
Below is my code which displays the time series properly but cross tab displays only half data.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report5" pageWidth="590" pageHeight="595" columnWidth="550" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="46"/>
    <style name="Crosstab Data Text" hAlign="Center"/>
    <parameter name="citizenID" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="ContactType" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="bloodGroup" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="MaritalStatus" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="DOB" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="citizenPhotoImg" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="ContactDetails" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="gender" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="address" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT     tbPatientMeasurement.MeasurementValue, tbPatientMeasurement.Taken, tbMeasurement.MeasurementName, tbPatientMeasurement.MeasurementIDF,
                      tbUOM.UOMName, tbPatientMeasurement.PatientMeasurementIDP, REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(19), CONVERT(DATETIME, DATEADD(month, 0,
                      tbPatientMeasurement.Taken), 101), 121), '-', ','), ' ', ','), ':', ',') AS Created, tbVitalDisplayConfig.SequenceID, tbPatientMeasurement.CitizenIDF
FROM         tbPatientMeasurement INNER JOIN
                      tbMeasurement ON tbPatientMeasurement.MeasurementIDF = tbMeasurement.MeasurementIDP INNER JOIN
                      tbUOM ON tbMeasurement.DefaultUOM = tbUOM.UOMIDP INNER JOIN
                      tbPatientChartConfig ON tbMeasurement.MeasurementIDP = tbPatientChartConfig.MeasurementIDF LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      tbVitalDisplayConfig ON tbMeasurement.MeasurementIDP = tbVitalDisplayConfig.MeasurementIDF
WHERE     (tbPatientMeasurement.CitizenIDF = 16)
ORDER BY CASE WHEN SequenceID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, tbVitalDisplayConfig.SequenceID]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="MeasurementValue" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Taken" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
    <field name="MeasurementName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="MeasurementIDF" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="UOMName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="PatientMeasurementIDP" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="SequenceID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="CitizenIDF" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="measurementName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="measurementValue" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="created" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="131">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="273" y="44" width="51" height="14"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{gender}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="324" y="56" width="78" height="14"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{ContactType}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="68" y="44" width="52" height="14"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[DOB :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="11" y="107" width="530" height="1"/>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="238" y="108" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Vital Chart]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="120" y="56" width="78" height="14"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{citizenID}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="200" y="56" width="73" height="14"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Marital Status : ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="324" y="44" width="78" height="14"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Blood Group :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="120" y="44" width="80" height="14"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{DOB}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <image>
                <reportElement x="10" y="10" width="58" height="70"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{citizenPhotoImg}]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="11" y="127" width="530" height="1"/>
            </line>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="402" y="44" width="136" height="14"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{bloodGroup}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="273" y="56" width="51" height="14"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{MaritalStatus}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="200" y="44" width="73" height="14"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Gender :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="402" y="58" width="136" height="14"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{ContactDetails}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="68" y="26" width="473" height="14"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{address}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="68" y="10" width="292" height="16"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="68" y="56" width="52" height="14"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[MedicoID : ]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <lastPageFooter>
        <band height="355">
            <timeSeriesChart>
                <chart isShowLegend="true" evaluationTime="Report" renderType="draw">
                    <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="550" height="322" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                    <chartTitle position="Top"/>
                    <chartSubtitle/>
                    <chartLegend/>
                </chart>
                <timeSeriesDataset timePeriod="Milisecond">
                    <timeSeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA[$F{measurementName}]]></seriesExpression>
                        <timePeriodExpression><![CDATA[new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy,MM,dd,HH,mm").parse($F{created})]]></timePeriodExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[Double.valueOf($F{measurementValue})]]></valueExpression>
                    </timeSeries>
                </timeSeriesDataset>
                <timeSeriesPlot isShowLines="true" isShowShapes="true">
                    <plot backgroundAlpha="1.0" labelRotation="55.0"/>
                </timeSeriesPlot>
            </timeSeriesChart>
        </band>
    </lastPageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="127" splitType="Stretch">
            <crosstab ignoreWidth="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="550" height="104"/>
                <crosstabHeaderCell>
                    <cellContents backcolor="#66FF33"/>
                </crosstabHeaderCell>
                <rowGroup name="Taken" width="0">
                    <bucket order="Descending" class="java.lang.String">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy")).format($F{Taken})]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabRowHeader>
                        <cellContents backcolor="#F0F8FF" mode="Opaque">
                            <box>
                                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement style="Crosstab Data Text" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0"/>
                                <textElement/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Taken}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabRowHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                        <cellContents/>
                    </crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                </rowGroup>
                <rowGroup name="Taken1" width="93">
                    <bucket order="Descending" class="java.lang.String">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm")).format($F{Taken})]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabRowHeader>
                        <cellContents backcolor="#F0F8FF" mode="Opaque">
                            <box>
                                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement style="Crosstab Data Text" x="0" y="0" width="93" height="16"/>
                                <textElement/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Taken1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabRowHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                        <cellContents/>
                    </crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                </rowGroup>
                <columnGroup name="SequenceID" height="0">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.Integer">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{SequenceID}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents backcolor="#F0F8FF" mode="Opaque">
                            <box>
                                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement style="Crosstab Data Text" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0"/>
                                <textElement>
                                    <font size="9"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{SequenceID}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabColumnHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents/>
                    </crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                </columnGroup>
                <columnGroup name="MeasurementName" height="21">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{MeasurementName}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents backcolor="#F0F8FF" mode="Opaque">
                            <box>
                                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement style="Crosstab Data Text" x="0" y="0" width="61" height="20"/>
                                <textElement/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{MeasurementName}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabColumnHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents/>
                    </crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                </columnGroup>
                <columnGroup name="UOMName" height="20">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{UOMName}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents backcolor="#F0F8FF" mode="Opaque">
                            <box>
                                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement style="Crosstab Data Text" x="0" y="0" width="61" height="20"/>
                                <textElement/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{UOMName}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabColumnHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents/>
                    </crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                </columnGroup>
                <measure name="MeasurementValueMeasure" class="java.lang.String">
                    <measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{MeasurementValue}]]></measureExpression>
                </measure>
                <crosstabCell width="61" height="16">
                    <cellContents>
                        <box>
                            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement style="Crosstab Data Text" x="0" y="0" width="61" height="16"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{MeasurementValueMeasure}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell height="25" rowTotalGroup="Taken">
                    <cellContents backcolor="#005FB3" mode="Opaque">
                        <box>
                            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement style="Crosstab Data Text" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="25" forecolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{MeasurementValueMeasure}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="50" columnTotalGroup="MeasurementName">
                    <cellContents backcolor="#005FB3" mode="Opaque">
                        <box>
                            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement style="Crosstab Data Text" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="25" forecolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{MeasurementValueMeasure}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell rowTotalGroup="Taken" columnTotalGroup="MeasurementName">
                    <cellContents backcolor="#005FB3" mode="Opaque">
                        <box>
                            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement style="Crosstab Data Text" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="25" forecolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{MeasurementValueMeasure}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="50" columnTotalGroup="UOMName">
                    <cellContents backcolor="#BFE1FF" mode="Opaque">
                        <box>
                            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement style="Crosstab Data Text" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="25"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{MeasurementValueMeasure}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell rowTotalGroup="Taken" columnTotalGroup="UOMName">
                    <cellContents backcolor="#005FB3" mode="Opaque">
                        <box>
                            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement style="Crosstab Data Text" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="25" forecolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{MeasurementValueMeasure}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell height="25" rowTotalGroup="Taken1">
                    <cellContents backcolor="#BFE1FF" mode="Opaque">
                        <box>
                            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement style="Crosstab Data Text" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="25"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{MeasurementValueMeasure}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell rowTotalGroup="Taken1" columnTotalGroup="MeasurementName">
                    <cellContents backcolor="#005FB3" mode="Opaque">
                        <box>
                            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement style="Crosstab Data Text" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="25" forecolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{MeasurementValueMeasure}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell rowTotalGroup="Taken1" columnTotalGroup="UOMName">
                    <cellContents backcolor="#BFE1FF" mode="Opaque">
                        <box>
                            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement style="Crosstab Data Text" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="25"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{MeasurementValueMeasure}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
            </crosstab>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try these two solutions:-

1:- Try to maximize the band height of both bands by right clicking on the band.

2:- Second option is too use "Report Group" , you can add two report group for chart and crosstab, to add report group go to "Report Inspector" right click on the report and then select "Add Report Group".

Comment: Added two report gropes and changed chart data report type(group)  but it still not working.in footer 1 i put time series and footer 2 i put cross tab so time series display properly but cross tab less data display

Comment: Did u try to put chart and cross tab in header of report groups?

Comment: its done 1 i put in header group and one in summery band......   thanks for your support.....